# How to access the element in this input using XPATH

Tags: xslt

I am using XPath to reach to a text value as shown in the input xml.

```
     <stream>
    <Services>
    <ServicesSub>
        <title>Parameter Calculations</title>
        <list1 type="unordered-bullet">
            <item>
                <premier>
                    <link Id="1222">Sheet Size</link>
                    <link Id="433">Hydraulic System</link>
                </premier>
            </item>
            <item>
                <premier> Review 
<link Id="342332">Diagnose</link>

Rational Approach</premier>
            </item>
            <item>
                <premier>
                    <link Id="222">Process</link>
                </premier>
            </item>
        </list1>
    </ServicesSub>
    <ServicesSub>
        <title>Parameter Set</title>
        <table TableNumber="tab1" titlesource="no-title" frame="all" pgwide="page-wide">
            <tgroup cols="5" colsep="1" rowsep="1" align="left" charoff="50" char="">
                <colspec ColumnName="col1" colwidth="2.77in"/>
                <colspec ColumnName="col2" colwidth="1.10in"/>

                  <thead valign="bottom">
                    <row RowNumber="row1">
                        <entry ColumnName="col1" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="bottom" align="center">
                            <ptxt>Price less</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                        <entry ColumnName="col2" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="bottom" align="center">
                            <ptxt>Price more</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                        <entry ColumnName="col3" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="bottom" align="center">
                            <ptxt>Open Price</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody valign="top">
                    <row RowNumber="row1">
                        <entry ColumnName="col1" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="middle">
                            <ptxt>Sheet</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                        <entry ColumnName="col2" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="middle" align="center">
                            <ptxt>Sheets1</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                    <row RowNumber="row2">
                        <entry ColumnName="col1" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="middle">
                            <ptxt>Electric failure</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                        <entry ColumnName="col2" morerows="0" rotate="0" valign="middle" align="center">
                            <ptxt>Elec fails</ptxt>
                        </entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
    </ServicesSub>
</Services>
</stream>
```

I am intersted only in the values "price less", "price more", "Open Price" under 'Parameter Set' title and under thead --> row --> entry.

I just started learning the xpath and xslt.. please help me in fetchin these values..

output expected:

```
<Value = "Price less"\>
<Value = "Price more"\>
<Value = "Open Price"\>
```

I tried until this...

```
/stream/Services/ServicesSub/title[text() = "Parameter Set" ]/following::*
```

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath which should return all matching **ptxt** elements.

```
stream/Services/ServicesSub
   [title[text() = 'Parameter Set']]/table/tgroup/thead/row/entry/ptxt
```

For example, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="stream/Services/ServicesSub[title[text() = 'Parameter Set']]/table/tgroup/thead/row/entry/ptxt"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ptxt">
      <value>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </value>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML produces the following output

```
<value>Price less</value>
<value>Price more</value>
<value>Open Price</value>
```

Note that you haven't mentioned about whether you have duplicate values, and how these should be handled. You need to read up on grouping (Muenchian Grouping in XSLT 1.0) if you have duplicates and want them ignored.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I missed out extra bracket before Title in my expression I am trying. Yes, I have duplicate values and space after Set in 'Parameter Set ', so not able to completely extract the data. How do I do these ?

Comment: If you can't work out how to remove duplicates using grouping, it is probably best then you ask another question, with the duplicates showing in your sample XML.